# A queue of pointers change its value

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, queue

When I push a pointer of struct into a std::queue, and then poping the value, the value that I'm getting back would change to zero. I've simplified the actual code to illustrate the problem below. The `head` pointer in the real code is a class variable and contains other values. If I push `head` onto the queue, all other values that I get also become uninitialized.

What could be the issue here?

Note: `PipePixel *head;` is an instance variable declared in the class header file.

Add Head Function:

```
void LinkedGraph::addHeadPixel(int index) {

    PipePixel pixel = {NULL, 433, std::vector<PipePixel*>()};
    pixel.index = index;

    if (head==NULL) {
        pixelMap[index] = &pixel;
        head = &pixel;
    } else {
        printf("Already added head pixel! Px:%d\n", pixelMap[index]->index);
    }
}
```

Print Function: <-- Where problem occurs

```
std::queue<PipePixel*> printQueue;
printQueue.push(head);
printf("headIndex:%d\n", head->index); // headIndex:433

while (!printQueue.empty()) {

    PipePixel *child = printQueue.front();
    printf("childIndex:%d\n", child->index); //childIndex:0
    printQueue.pop();

    if (child == NULL) {
        printf("child is null"); // no output
        continue;
    }  
}
```

PipePixel Struct:

```
struct PipePixel {

    PipePixel *parent;
    int index; //pixel index
    std::vector<PipePixel*> children;
};
```

Comment: *Where* do you declare the `pixel` variable? Is it in another scope (like in another function) than where you have your printing loop? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: hope the changes help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the variable `pixel` is local inside the `LinkedGraph::addHeadPixel` function. Once the function returns that object is destructed and the variable ceases to exist. If you have stored a pointer to a local variable, that pointer no longer points to a valid object, and dereferencing the pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

My recommendation is to not use pointers at all, but let the compiler handle he object copying. For such small and simple objects its possible performance impact is negligible.

Comment: @SiTeFeng When simplifying code, it's often better to try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just "simplifying" existing code often leads to unrelated mistakes that makes the real problem hard to see.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But how come when I print `head` the first time it produces a valid value same as initialized? I've read that C++ reference counting keeps the variable around if it's been referenced. But it could also be garbage data that hasn't been overwritten like you said.

Comment: @SiTeFeng C++ doesn't have reference counting of objects. One of the possibilities of undefined behavior is that it might *seem* to work fine.